# Pod Updation in MAC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, macos, rubygems

Hello Developer's I am new to ios and i previously installed the cocoapods in my MAC .Now i was reset my MacBook Air. then i am trying to install the pods to my Project the error showing like "    `ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rubygems-update' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version ("`

So firstly i checked which version of pods currently installed in my Mac

Here is my pods envirnoment

```
$ gem env 
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14.1
- RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 648) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- universal-darwin-16
- GEM PATHS:
- /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
- /Users/dtimac13/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
- /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
- :update_sources => true
- :verbose => true
- :backtrace => false
- :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
- https://rubygems.org/
```

when i am trying install pods to my project error message is showing like

```
1:$ cd /Users/dtimac13/Desktop/RaviTejaEX 
2:$ pico podfile
3:$ pod install
-bash: pod: command not found
```

Help me .Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the version of SSL that shipped with the version of ruby is out of date, and you'll need to update your version of ruby:

> As a result, RubyGems.org will require TLSv1.2 at minimum starting January 2018. This means RubyGems.org and the gem command will no longer support versions of Ruby and OpenSSL that are do not have support of TLS 1.2.

You can follow this guide, but I recommend upgrading to the latest version of ruby: https://bundler.io/v1.16/guides/rubygems_tls_ssl_troubleshooting_guide.html#the-solutions

Comment: Hello thank's for the suggestion .I follow the link for resolve the issue but in above link when i run the script $ ruby -ropen-uri -e 'eval open("https://git.io/vQhWq").read' error message  displayed like command not found .can you explain me why

Comment: Sorry not sure, seems like you’ll need to follow the instructions in the link i posted.